# Php fatal error: but still sends form values to email

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a quote form that has a dropdown menu which is giving me an php fatal error after submitting form. The form and values is still sent to me in email but I get this error:  PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in G:..... on line 60. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my html for dropdown

```
<select name="item"  id="item" >
  <option value="Please Select" selected>Please Select</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
  <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
  <option value="Tools">Tools</option>
  <option value="Lawn Equipment">Lawn Equipment</option>
  <option value="Guns">Guns</option>
  <option value="Musical Instrument">Musical Instrument</option>
  <option value="Collectible">Collectible</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

And here is part of my php

```
         <?php

$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_selectitem = $_POST['selectitem'];
$field_make = $_POST['make'];
$field_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$field_model = $_POST['model'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_comments = $_POST['comments'];
    if (isset($_POST['mailing'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
    } else {
    $checkBoxValue = "no";
        }


      //FORM DETAILS     
           $name = $_POST['name']; // required
           $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
           $item = $_POST['item']; // required
           $make = $_POST['phone']; // required
           $phone = $_POST['make'];
           $model = $_POST['model'];
           $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
           $mailing = $_POST['mailing'];

        // Values from dropdown menu
            echo'<select name="item">'; 

         // For each value of the array assign variable name "items" 
                foreach($field_item as $key =>
                       $value){ 
                    echo"<option value=\"$key\">
                    $value</option>\n"; 
                        } 
                         echo'</select>';   


                      // FORM DETAILS EMAIL
                      $mail_to = 'highlandguns.contact@gmail.com';
                      $subject = 'Item Quote Request Form Results '.$name;


            //EMAIL MESSAGE DETAILS     
               $body_message .= 'Name: '.$field_name."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Item Type: '.$field_item."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Make: '.$field_make."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Model: '.$field_model."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Comments: '.$field_comments."\n";
               $body_message .= 'Join Mailing List:'.$checkBoxValue;



               //EMAIL HEADERS
               $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
               $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

               $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

                     ?>
```

Line 60 error is the foreach ($field_item..... =>

Comment: If your select is to contain multiple choices, you would need to use `<select name="item"  id="item" multiple>`, otherwise, you don't need the `foreach`.

Comment: The warning you are getting is because PHP can't iterate over `$field_item`.  Likely the problem is that it isn't an array.  How is the `$field_item` variable assigned?

Comment: I added the rest of my php minus validating.

Comment: you are looping the array `$field_item` which doesn't exist ..

Comment: I get the email w ith all values just doesn't take me to success page and I get the error.